Always gettiing redirected to the login and not able to disble csrf in spring boot authentication, authorization public urls also needauthentication
`
Always gettiing redirected to the login and not able to disble csrf in spring boot      authentication, authorization public urls also needauthentication
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    return http
        .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())  
        .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
            .requestMatchers("/home/", "/register/**").permitAll()  
            .requestMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")  
            .requestMatchers("/user/**").hasRole("USER")  
            .anyRequest().authenticated()  
        )
        .formLogin(form -> form
            .permitAll()  
        )
        .build();  
}

@Bean
public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
    UserDetails normalUser = User.builder()
            .username("gc")
            .password("$2a$12$pLlEDlW7J3LJMLMl0Uv8Xu.NO1TYDvrMmIpoDhpHZ3So65XlsR.Vy")  
            .roles("USER")
            .build();
             UserDetails adminUser = User.builder()
            .username("admin")
            .password("$2a$12$4MVGfzHJ2C370at3MTGHdeX6z/kon2X5KbVWZTGfqjWBhj.KnQBuC") 
            .roles("ADMIN", "USER")
            .build();
    return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(normalUser, adminUser);
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

}
`

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

What is the exact issue you're having, can you add some reproduction steps?
